$\lambda_{max}(A) = \sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}x}$ and $\lambda_{min}(A) = \inf_{x\neq 0} \frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}x}$ when A is symmetric?
Suppose we are on $\mathbb{R}$ and $A\in R^{n,n}$ is symmetric, $\lambda_{max}(A), \lambda_{min}(A)$ denotes the largest and smallest eigenvalues of A respectively. Does
$$\lambda_{max}(A) = \sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}x}$$
$$\lambda_{min}(A) = \inf_{x\neq 0} \frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}x}$$
hold?
They hold when A is positive semidefinite, since we can treat $\frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}x}$ as$\frac{(A^{1/2}x)^{T}A^{1/2}x}{x^{T}x}$, and $A$'s eigenvalues are squares of $A^{1/2}$'s singular values. The above two statements are then just properties of linear map norm.
But what if A is just symmetric? Do these two equations still hold?

This seems to be what is implied in the book Convex Optimization on p647

Yes, it is true. By the spectral theorem we can diagonalize our matrix unitarily. Thus, we can write $A=U^T \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n) U$. As unitary matrices do not change the norm of a vector, we get for $x\neq 0$ $$ \frac{x^T A x}{x^T x} = \frac{(Ux)^T \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n) (U  x)}{x^T x} = \frac{y^T \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n) y}{y^T y} $$ where $y=Ux$. Now you can use this to take the infimum, respectively the supremum.

Ahh how elegant, thanks for the enlightenment!

You are very welcome. I suggest you write an answer yourself, including the details. Then you can see whether you have understood the idea and also gain some reputation :)

Well my way of understanding it may not be the cleverest, but sure, I shall try my best.

I think you did a great job at writing this down.

Thank you! It was good practice.

(Thanks @SeverinSchraven for the hint.)
Using spectral theorem we can perform a change of basis on $A$ to get $Q^{-1}diag(\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n})Q$, where $\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n}$ are the eigenvalues of A, Q is an unitary matrix. Also note $Q^{-1} = Q^{T}$ for unitary matrices.
Then
$$\sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}x} = \sup_{x\neq 0} \frac{(Qx)^{T}diag(\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n})Qx}{x^{T}x} = \sup_{y\neq 0} \frac{y^{T}diag(\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n})y}{y^{T}y} = \sup_{y\neq 0}\frac{\lambda_{1}y_{1}^{2}+...+\lambda_{n}y_{n}^{2}}{y_{1}^{2}+...+y_{n}^{2}} = \lambda_{max} $$
where $y = Qx$, and the second equality holds since a unitary matrix does not change the norm of a vector (hence $x^{T}x=y^{T}y$), and also an unitary matrix is invertible (hence Q is an isomorphism on $R^{n}$, this means we can change the variable from x to y as shown). To see why the fourth equality holds, view $\frac{\lambda_{1}y_{1}^{2}+...+\lambda_{n}y_{n}^{2}}{y_{1}^{2}+...+y_{n}^{2}}$ as a $y_{i}^{2}$-weighted average of $\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n}$.
Analogously,
$$\inf_{x\neq 0} \frac{x^{T}Ax}{x^{T}x} = \inf_{x\neq 0} \frac{(Qx)^{T}diag(\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n})Qx}{x^{T}x} = \inf_{y\neq 0} \frac{y^{T}diag(\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{n})y}{y^{T}y} = \inf_{y\neq 0}\frac{\lambda_{1}y_{1}^{2}+...+\lambda_{n}y_{n}^{2}}{y_{1}^{2}+...+y_{n}^{2}} = \lambda_{min}$$
and we are done.
